# How to read from a file that is in use

Tags: java, c++, c, windows

There's a file I wanted to get into, but whenever I try to open it I get the message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".

Well, I want in! So, how can i do it?

I've been brainstorming a few ways to try, I'm hoping to get some input on other ways, or if my ideas wouldn't work for some reason that is not apparent to me.

- **Idea 1** The folder knows where the file is, it just won't open it. What if I create a program to read from the memory address of the file, copy it, then rebuild it somewhere else? I'm not sure if this has hope, because it relies on the file being the issue.
- **Idea 2** How does my process know that another process is using the file? If it's checking against all the other processes, maybe I can also figure out which process is using that file and pause it or end it.

Either of these ideas will probably take me weeks. Is anyone more creative and can think of another way; or more knowledgeable and eliminate an impractical idea?

Comment: Using a copy of the file?

Comment: "The action can't be completed because the file is open in System", The file is supposedly in use somewhere and I want to get around that

Comment: [openfiles command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732490(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: openfiles command looks promising, I'll keep this as a last resort. I want to avoid disconnecting if possible, since it's a system process and I'm not sure what the effect will be

Comment: You should re-examine *why* you need to do this. Possibly you should be using a database instead?

Comment: If you really have to access a file that is in use, the only safe way to do so is using the Volume Shadow Copy Service.  Forcing the other process to close the file is liable to make that process malfuction; in the case of the system, it could cause the entire system to become unstable.  Depending on the scenario, MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT may be a safer alternative.

Comment: What file are you trying to access, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, applications are allowed to obtain exclusive [locks on files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking).  When the process [opens the file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx), one thing you specify is [who else can access it while your process does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) (those are the .NET methods, but equivalents exist in other languages).  Excel, for example, is notorious for getting an exclusive lock when you open a file.  The way around it is usually [to find the offending process and kill it](https://superuser.com/questions/93567/removing-locks-on-files-in-windows-7) to break the lock.  Unlocker is the app that I'm most familiar with to accomplish this.  If the process is a System process, however, you may not be able to kill it.  You'd have to reboot to reset the lock.

Reading directly from another process's memory is unlikely to be reliable.  The application may not have an in-memory copy, may not have a complete in memory copy, may not have a consistent in memory copy, and may not have an in memory copy that matches what's on disk (If they're editing the document, for example).

Your process knows that the file is locked because when it tries to open the file, it does so by asking the operating system for access to the file.  The operating system responds saying, "Request denied.  Another process has this file open and locked."  The OS doesn't tell your process what process has the file open because trying to open a file doesn't include asking for who already has it open.  Your process must ask the right question to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: "Reading directly from another process's memory is unlikely to be reliable" -  will Windows even let you do this? afaik, the OS gives each process its own virtual memory space.

Comment: Great info, since it's the operating system saying no, there probably won't be an issue if I just directly read its bytes (without opening it)

Comment: @RedAlert Yes, see ReadProcessMemory: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RedAlert Windows will let you do that.  That's how process dumps and online debuggers work.  Data Execution Prevention doesn't exist to reveal shoddy coding -- it does that by as a side effect -- it exists to prevent third party programs from changing things a program has labelled as data and make it that much harder to take control of a system by writing directly to memory.

Answer (score 1):

Windows makes you specify a sharing modes when opening a file. The sharing mode may prevent the file from being read, written, or deleted while you have it open. If you want to allow simultaneous read access you should include `FILE_SHARE_READ` in the `dwShareMode` parameter when you call `CreateFile` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

In other words, if you want to enable concurrent access to an open file you must modify the way the file is opened in the first place.

The portable standard libraries in C and Java don't offer a way to set the sharing mode when opening a file, but their usual implementations on windows set the sharing mode to READ+WRITE.

Comment: This isn't an issue about permissions (I'm reasonably sure), the file is already in use by the system so it won't let me open another version.

Comment: This is not about permissions but about exclusive access, which is a different security feature. If you find a way to access the file in a way the operating system should not permit you should file a bug with the OS.